# Find the pairs (2 Elements) from an array whose product must be greater then given Integer

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I got this question in an Interview. 
Suppose you have an **unsorted integer** array with possible values positive, negative and zero. You also have a variable `k` which holds an Integer. Now find the pair or pairs, non-repetitive, if exists, whose product is greater then `k`.
`k` can be anything, +ve, -ve, or zero

**Constraints**: You cannot manipulate the array, means any sorting or making a copy of original and then sorting or changing the values is restricted.

If possible it should be lower then `O(n^2)` Time Complexity and minimum Space (not mentioned clearly for space, but they said use lowest possible)

**For Example**: given `Array [0,-1, 5, 45, 4, 1, -3]` and `k = 20`
My Solution is given during interview:

**My Solution**:
First one was Brute-Force using `O(N^2)` and trying to get the product for that pair and checking. Now I improvised that to the following logic

Suppose `k = 40`, and I got `array[i] = 2`. Now `int divide = k/array[i]`. 
`divide+ = 1`. If I encounter any number say `array[j] > divide`, and `array[j] < k`, then the product of `int product = array[i] * array[j]` will be `product > k`.

**Logic**:
If I have a number 1000 and I got the `array[i] = 3` for some value of `i`. If I get `n = 1000 / array[i]` and increment `n = n+1`, and if `n` is present in array then the product of `n * array[i] > 1000`

**EDIT**: +ve means Positive, -ve Means Negative, And find **all the pairs** instead of stopping at first pair. **EDIT 2** We can store minimum number of entries in any new Data Structure, but it should be Minimum, not a full copy of original or too many elements in that Data Struction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we have:

```
int[] values;
int k;
// Found pairs will be fed to this consumer
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> results;
```

The naive brute-force implementation is `O(n^2)`. The question is, if it is possible to make it better. I personally do not think so. In the worst case all elements of the array could form pairs. For instance if array contains distinct positive integers and `k=0`. Even if you'd sort an array, you'd still need to actually produce pairs. This means that brute-force is actually good enough.

Now for the space complexity. The problem is that you need to produce *non-repetetive* pairs. So you need some tracking of which pairs you have already seen and which not. Naively that's `O(n^2)` but I think this could be reduced to `O(n)`.

Here's a sketch of code:

```
Set<Integer> seenNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
    int left = values[i];

    if (seenNumbers.contains(right)) {
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
        int right = values[j];

        if (seenNumbers.contains(right)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (((long)left*(long)right) > k) {
            results.accept(left, right);
            if (left != right) {
                results.accept(right, left);
            }
        }
    }
    seenNumbers.add(left);
}
```

This code uses `O(n)` of additional space for `seenNumbers`. I think it is enough to only track already encountered numbers. If we encounter certain number *again*, it means it was already processed as `values[i]`, which means that all possible pairs with this number were already generated.

I've desided again the "division" solution you've suggested. Because it's quite tricky. You can't just `k/values[i] + 1` and use it as minimum for right. You need to account for `values[i]==0` as well as for negative `values[i]`. Not that it's impossible but it is very cumbersome and extremely easy to make a mistake. I'd probably mention this on the interview but rather not do it. Simple multiplication is much easier.

But even with simple multiplication you have to consider integer overflow. Therefor `(long)left*(long)right`. This is often a catch on interviews, Google loves it. :)

Comment: I just noticed that this sollution will skip `(values[i], values[j])` solution if `values[i]==values[j]`.